# Retrofit2 Add extra string to Body object

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Basically what im trying to do it's this.

First of all this is my **APIService.kt**

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("api/v1/UsuarioController/saveDataPerson")
    abstract fun saveDataPerson(@Body email: String,@Body Person: Person): Call<Person>
```

the error goes with **email: String** i know that for this kind of request the best way it's to create a class with the values requested and obtained from the json, however i don't want to create the same value email in my **Person.kt**

the structure it's this

**Person.kt**

```
class Person : Serializable {
    var user: User
    var imc: String
    var name: String
    var gender: Boolean
    var age: Int
    var height: Float
    var weight: Float

    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String? = null

    constructor(user: User,imc: String, name: String, gender: Boolean, age: Int, height: Float, weight: Float){
        this.user = User
        this.imc = imc
        this.name = name
        this.gender = gender
        this.age = age
        this.height = height
        this.weight= weight
    }
}
```

and this is the other class where i call email(for login, signUp)

**User.kt**

```
class Usuario() : Serializable {
    var rol: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    var pass: String = ""
    var active: Boolean = false

    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String? = null

    constructor(rol: String, email: String, pass: String, active: Boolean): this(){
        this.rol = rol;
        this.email = email;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

and the class where this goes in action.

```
private fun registerPersonalData(){
        btnBMI.isClickable = false
        btnBMI.startAnimation()
        val person = restManager!!.getApiService()!!.saveDataPerson(Person(User("rol",commonMethod.getUserPreferenceValue(),"password",true),commonMethod.categoryBMI(commonMethod.calcBMI(commonMethod.calcHeightMeters(et_height.text.toString().toFloat(),heightRadioSelect.position.toString().toInt()),commonMethod.calcWeightKilograms(et_weight.text.toString().toFloat(),weightRadioSelect.position.toString().toInt()))),et_name.text.toString(),genderRadioSelect.position.toString().toBoolean(),age.toInt(),et_height.text.toString().toFloat(),et_weight.text.toString().toFloat()))
        person.enqueue(object : Callback<Person> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Person>, response: retrofit2.Response<Person>) {
                when(response.body()?.message){
                    "Empty Fields"->Toast.makeText(this@RegisterBMIActivity,getString(R.string.invalid_data),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    "No linked account"->Toast.makeText(this@RegisterBMIActivity,getString(R.string.no_associated_account),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    "No IMC linked"->Toast.makeText(this@RegisterBMIActivity,getString(R.string.bmi_unknown),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    "Invalid data"-> Toast.makeText(this@RegisterBMIActivity,getString(R.string.invalid_data),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    "Success"->registroExitoso()
                    else -> Toast.makeText(this@RegisterBMIActivity,getString(R.string.unknown_error),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                btnBMI.isClickable = true
                btnBMI.doneLoadingAnimation(R.color.md_yellow_300, (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.check)))
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Person>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("error", t.message)
                btnBMI.isClickable = true
                btnBMI.revertAnimation()
            }
        })
    }
```

And well the objective that i want to achieve it's to add **email** to my @Body without add that field into the **Person.kt**

please advice me :(

[[EDITED]]

This is the new content that throws when the JSON Fail...

> E/error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but
>   was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
>
> E/errors:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

Answer (score 0):

A call can have 1 body parameter.
Only 1.

So you'd have to create a new class, like "RequestUser" that extends the "User" class, and then add the "email" field in that class.

So you use "User" class in your app, but when you want to make a request, you create a new "RequestUser" object that copies all the data from a "User" object, and add the email to the "RequestUser" object, and use that to do the request with.

Also, please, write your code in english. It makes it impossible to read your code when half of it is in some other language.

Comment: well i change the code to english (my bad) also, when i extend the class User, i get a malformed exception however i can't visualize the JSON that i send and recieve :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call your Object to be assigned, it doesn't match with the current structure that you're receiving.